# Windows file share inside linux container - volume 'driver' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add a windows file share as a volume in a Linux docker container

my docker.compose is as follows

```
version: '3.4'
    
services:
  dealproducer:
    image: MyService:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyService/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./sidecar/shm:/dev/shm
      - ./sidecar/ORG.conf:/etc/krb5.conf.d/ORG.conf
    depends_on:
      - authentication
     
  authentication:
    image: myorg:101/ubi8/kerberos-sidecar:latest
    volumes:
      - ./sidecar/shm:/dev/shm
      - C:/temp/keytab/xbrmdock.keytab:/krb5/krb5.keytab
    environment:
      - SERVICE_ACCOUNT=srvcaccad
volumes:
    filewatchshare:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=myuser,password=mypass,rw,domain=mydomain
      device: "\\\\sharedfolder\\Reports"
```

I get the following error when I run the command `docker-compose up -d`

> .\docker-compose.yml', volume 'driver' must be a mapping not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect nesting under `volumes`. Try this:

```yaml
volumes:
  filewatchshare:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=myuser,password=mypass,rw,domain=mydomain
      device: "\\\\sharedfolder\\Reports"
```